# How to populate Formtastic :select input value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, formtastic

I am using Formtastic with an :as => :selected input for a FLOAT field in the DB that has a fixed list of valid values. My form view code for this Formtastic input (field in DB :verticalCDR) is:

```
<%= clr.input :verticalCDR, :label => "Vertical CDR: ", :as => :select, 
:collection => [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0], 
:wrapper_html => { :class => "CRF_Field" }  %>
```

When the form is submitted the value is properly saved to the DB, but if the same record is viewed again, the current value from the DB is not the selected value in the :select input. It is blank.

All other inputs in the form are working as expected.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. Apparently the collection should use strings even though that field is numeric. Changing the collection to:

```
<%= clr.input :verticalCDR, :label => "Vertical CDR: ", :as => :select, 
:collection => ["0.0", "0.05", "0.1", "0.15", "0.2", "0.25", "0.3", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", "0.5", "0.55", "0.6", "0.65", "0.7", "0.75", "0.8", "0.85", "0.9", "0.95", "1.0"], 
:wrapper_html => { :class => "CRF_Field" }  %>
```

I am guessing it has to do with conversion to/from string types, although this seems somewhat undesirable to me.

Comment: This is possibly a bug in Formtastic at the moment, but glad you're up and running either way.

Comment: @JustinFrench I may have spoken too soon... it appears this works on DEV system, but not after deployment to production system. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @justinFench Looks like with or without quotes, the select :collection works in development mode, and not in production.